# React MUI input border color variable

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using MUI, and it styling solution (JSS) for my website. I was wondering if is there a variable in the theme object (or function ?) to get the basic input (TextField for exemple) border color, it's basicly rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28) or equivalent in white, but can't find it in the default theme.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't in the theme, it is [hard-coded in OutlinedInput](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.3/packages/material-ui/src/OutlinedInput/OutlinedInput.js#L10):

```
const borderColor = theme.palette.type === 'light' ? 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23)' : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.23)';
```

and then used for the `notchedOutline` styles:

```
    /* Styles applied to the `NotchedOutline` element. */
    notchedOutline: {
      borderColor,
    },
```